# GCP metadata access from startup script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am launching GCP instances from my python code using the `googleapiclient` libraries. Now, I am passing the AWS credentials as metadata to the instance configuration:

Now, I am trying to access this metadata from my start up script, which is also passed as a metadata [key, value] pair. In my startup script, I access the metadata as follows:

```
getMetadata() {
  curl -fs http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/$1 \
    -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
}

aws_access_key_id=`getMetadata aws_access_key_id`
aws_secret_access_key=`getMetadata aws_secret_access_key`

echo 'export aws_access_key_id = aws_access_key_id' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export aws_secret_access_key = $aws_secret_access_key' >> ~/.bashrc
```

This does not seem to have any effect for some reason. The strange thing is that when I `ssh`  into the instance, I can see that the metadata server has these key values pairs but I am not sure why they are not getting accessed in the startup script.

Additionally, I do not even see the export statements in my `.bashrc` file, even with the empty values. So, not sure what is happening.

For completeness, here is the full startup script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "Installing docker"
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
apt-get update
apt-cache policy docker-ce
apt-get install -y docker-ce make

echo "Checking for CUDA and installing."
# Check for CUDA and try to install.
if ! dpkg-query -W cuda-10-0; then
  curl -O http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
  wget -qO - https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub | sudo apt-key add -
  dpkg -i ./cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1.243-1_amd64.deb
  apt-get update
  apt-get install cuda -y
fi

# Enable persistence mode
nvidia-smi -pm 1
nvidia-smi --auto-boost-default=DISABLED

echo "Installing nvidia docker"
# Add the package repositories
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | apt-key add -
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
apt-get update

apt-get update && apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit
sudo systemctl restart docker

getMetadata() {
  curl -fs http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/$1 \
    -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
}

aws_access_key_id=`getMetadata aws_access_key_id`
aws_secret_access_key=`getMetadata aws_secret_access_key`

echo 'export aws_access_key_id = aws_access_key_id' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export aws_secret_access_key = $aws_secret_access_key' >> ~/.bashrc
```

The other thing is that everything else upto that point has been run fine. The console log does not also show any error.

**EDIT**

So I put some `echo` statements and looked at the console logs and the key and password seems to be retrieved correctly but the lines:

```
echo 'export aws_access_key_id = $aws_access_key_id' >> ~/.bashrc
```

seem to not have any effect. Not sure if the file gets overwritten or something but I also tried:

```
echo 'export aws_access_key_id = $aws_access_key_id' >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

but no joy.

Comment: 1) You have the `curl` option `-f` which means fail silently. Remove that. 2) Reboot and check the console log. 3) In your startup script install Stackdriver logging. 4) Does anything appear in Stackdriver after that? The entire startup process should be logged then.

Comment: @JohnHanley I made some edits based on your suggestion.

Comment: You made changes I did not suggest and ignore the changes I suggested.

Comment: I looked at the console logs and Slackdriver did not report anything unusual. Also removed thre `-f` option but nothing came up. Anyway, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Where in your startup script are you installing Stackdriver? If you want help, your details must be accurate. I asked for Stackdriver logs and you do not even have Stackdriver installed. First step, remove everything from your startup script that is not related to the problem you are trying to solve. Don't tell us what Stackdriver reports, include the output from Stackdriver in your question.

Comment: Ok, the issue is that the startup script in GCP runs as the root user, which is why the direct to `.bashrc` had no effect. In my case, it was fine to just use thhe python requests library later in my app running on the VM to get the params from the metadata server.

Answer (score 1):

Startup script runs as root user when you start/reset Google VM Instance.

I suggest using the full path in the startup script.
So, replace

```
echo 'export aws_access_key_id = $aws_access_key_id' >> ~/.bashrc
```

with

```
echo 'export aws_access_key_id=$aws_access_key_id' >> /root/.bashrc
```

Also, you need to remove spaces before and after `=` when you export UNIX environment variable.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The tilde (~) is shorthand for the user home directory, since you are using a startup script you are not logging into the system so there is no value for (~). I would use the full path to the `~/.bashrc` file you want to edit.

If you want to set this up for all users then go with `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` per [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503216/how-can-i-set-a-single-bashrc-file-for-several-users/503222) in askubuntu